# When using a cloud firestore listener, the unity editor gets stuck on "Application.Reload" after stopping and restarting the player

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I'm using Cloud Firestore in my unity app, and I've attached a listener as follows:

```
public void ListenForFirestoreChange()
{
    DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document(user.UserId);
    docRef.Listen(snapshot => {
            
        Dictionary<string, object> userEntry = snapshot.ToDictionary();
        Debug.Log("change detected: " + snapshot.Id + " " + (string)userEntry["firestoreTime"]);
    });
}
```

This is working great, but when I stop the player and restart it, unity gets stuck loading with the message "Application.Reload". I've tried stopping the listener onApplicationQuit, as well as setting my firestore reference to null, but that didn't work. I'm forced to end the Unity process, if I try to exit normally it gets stuck on Application.Quit. I've narrowed down the app getting stuck to this listener and I'm baffled.

I'm using :
Unity 2020.1.10f1

Visual Studio 16.7.6

Firebase for Unity 6.16.1

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to fix this issue after trying tons of things.
To fix this:

In an onApplicationQuit function, call

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a **mistake** to use "FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Dispose();" because you delete all Firebase related instances so you would have to re-initialize everything again.

If you do not want to close the application and you only want to log out of your application you should do it this way

According to the [docu](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es#unity) you have to use the function "listener.Stop();".

So in this case you must use it in the following way:

```
public void ListenForFirestoreChange(){

    DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document(user.UserId);

    ListenerRegistration listener = docRef.Listen(snapshot => {
        
    Dictionary<string, object> userEntry = snapshot.ToDictionary();
    Debug.Log("change detected: " + snapshot.Id + " " + (string)userEntry["firestoreTime"]);

});}
```

And when you want to delete the listens you must execute the following function:

```
listener.Stop();
```